# Loading Default Printer fails in the MFC MDI application only in Window 7 32 Bit, 64 Bit Working Fine

Tags: windows, visual-c++, printing, mfc, mdi

I have developed a MFC based MDI application using **VC 2008**. This application is running smooth in almost all the operating system.

But in the case of Win 7 32 Bit and if set with a printer other than XPS, the application fails to start and hangs and fails to show up. But the process will be still in the task manager.

On diagnosis, I found that the application was continuously trying to load Printer Drivers and not even reaching my application's Main Window Startup and Loading resources.

The Loading sequence on hang is as follows.

```
GetProcAddress(0x6FB90000 [c:\windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV], "GetPrinterW") called from "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MFW.DLL" at address 0x03096EEA and returned 0x6FB9BAC8.
GetProcAddress(0x6FB90000 [c:\windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV], "GetPrinterW") called from "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MFW.DLL" at address 0x03096EEA and returned 0x6FB9BAC8.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3maddprinter.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291919.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MADDPRINTER.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3maddprinter.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3maddprinter.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291A45.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MADDPRINTER.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3maddprinter.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mbase.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291919.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MBASE.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x046D0002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mbase.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x046D0002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mbase.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291A45.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MBASE.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x046D0002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mbase.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x046D0002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mbase.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291919.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MBASE.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x046D0002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mbase.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x046D0002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mbase.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291A45.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MBASE.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x046D0002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mbase.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x046D0002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mbase.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291919.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MBASE.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x046D0002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mbase.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x046D0002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mbase.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291A45.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MBASE.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x046D0002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mbase.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x046D0002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mdevicesettings.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291919.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MDEVICESETTINGS.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mdevicesettings.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mdevicesettings.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291A45.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MDEVICESETTINGS.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mdevicesettings.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3meffect.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291919.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MEFFECT.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3meffect.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3meffect.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291A45.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MEFFECT.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3meffect.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mhsp.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291919.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MHSP.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mhsp.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mhsp.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291A45.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MHSP.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mhsp.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mimagequality.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291919.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MIMAGEQUALITY.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mimagequality.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mimagequality.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291A45.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MIMAGEQUALITY.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mimagequality.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3monetouch.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291919.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MONETOUCH.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3monetouch.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3monetouch.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291A45.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MONETOUCH.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3monetouch.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mpagehandling.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291919.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MPAGEHANDLING.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mpagehandling.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mpagehandling.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291A45.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MPAGEHANDLING.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mpagehandling.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mtandemprint.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291919.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MTANDEMPRINT.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mtandemprint.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mtandemprint.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) called from "c:\windows\system32\VERSION.DLL" at address 0x75291A45.
Mapped "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MTANDEMPRINT.DLL" as a data file into memory at address 0x02860002.
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\W32X86\3\eSf3mtandemprint.dll", 0x00000000, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | 0x00000020) returned 0x02860002.
GetProcAddress(0x6FB90000 [c:\windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV], "OpenPrinterW") called from "c:\windows\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\ESF3MFW.DLL" at address 0x0309750C and returned 0x6FB968E8.
```

Things I have tried after, which did not succeed in bringing up the application.

1. Set the Compatibility Mode for my Apllication to "Windows XP"
2. Turned Off the UAC

Am I missing something? Please help.

EDIT 1: Sorry it is not VC6, it is VC 2008.

Comment: Have you tried downloading updated printer drivers?

Comment: "Am I missing something?" The 21st century, perhaps? VC6 is literally last century.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Yesh I tried that too. The application was showing the same signs.

Comment: @MSalters Yep, but the business still wants to keep that.

Comment: @SathishGuru: Sounds like a good case to report back as "known issue due to outdated technology; no Microsoft updates expected to fix this" and leave it at that. Perhaps you could move the printing functionality into a delay-loaded DLL and simply not support printing? That's just mitigating the problem of course, not fixing it.